# IOS 5 emoji unicode

Tags: android, iphone, ios5, ios4, emoji

I'm developing an android application that uses iphone ios5 emoji.

I was able to decode the ios 4 emoji unicodes but the problem is with ios 5.

As debugging my code, I found that ios5 emoji unicode use utf-16 shown [here](http://punchdrunker.github.com/iOSEmoji/table_html/)

The problem is that the one emoji is represented by two characters .. for example the first emoji is seen as 0xD83D 0xDE04

In decoding operation I do the following:

```
<item>\uD83D\uDE04</item>
```

when android see this unicode, it must replace it with emoji image.
but this doesn't work with me

Note: in the previous version (ios 4) when I do the following:

```
<item>\ue415</item>
```

the parser works well and decode this unicode to emoji
but when the item became more than one character it doesn't
how can I solve the problem ?